# Google Earth Enterprise Portal 5.0 Accessible via localhost only

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

Good Morning. I have downloaded and installed GE Enterprise portal v5. When I start the application, it automatically launches the browser and sends me to http://localhost:9335. It loads just fine and I am able to view the image and polygon. I then close the server and open the portable.cfg and added the following line: accept_all_requests True, which us supposed to allow others to view and use the published globes and services from other machines. I then restart the application. When I try and navigate to my portal instance via another machine or via the named machine name http://9335 I get page not found. I have tried changing the ports, disabling my local firewall and HIPs with no luck. Are you supposed to be able to hit an instance of portal from a url other than localhost?

Thanks.